# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'projectAverage' was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, stack, overflow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double hw = 0, hwTotal = 0, hwAverage[3], id[3], project = 0, projTotal = 0, projectAverage[3], hwProj, finalExam[3], total[3];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        cout << "Input student ID: ";
        cin >> id[i];
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            cout << "Input homework assignment grade: ";
            cin >> hw;

            hwTotal = hwTotal + hw;
        }

        hwAverage[j] = hwTotal / 4;

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            cout << "Input project grade: ";
            cin >> project;

            projTotal = projTotal + project;
        }

        projectAverage[j] = projTotal / 2;

        hwProj = (hwAverage[j] + projectAverage[j]) / 2;

        cout << "Input final exam grade: ";
        cin >> finalExam[j];

        total[j] = (finalExam[j] + hwProj) / 2;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++){
        cout << "Student ID: " << id[k] << endl;
        cout << "Homework Average: " << hwAverage[k] << endl;
        cout << "Project Average: " << projectAverage[k] << endl;
        cout << "Final exam grade: " << finalExam[k] << endl;
        cout << "Final average: " << total[k] << endl;

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, when I run this code, my output looks like this:

> - Input student ID: 123
> - Input homework assignment grade: 100
> - Input homework assignment grade: 100
> - Input homework assignment grade: 100
> - Input homework assignment grade: 100
> - Input project grade: 100
> - Input project grade: 100
> - Input final exam grade: 100
> - Input student ID: 12
> - Input homework assignment grade: 40
> - Input homework assignment grade: 40
> - Input homework assignment grade: 40
> - Input homework assignment grade: 40
> - Input project grade: 40
> - Input project grade: 40
> - Input final exam grade: 40
> - Input student ID: 1
> - Input homework assignment grade: 20
> - Input homework assignment grade: 20
> - Input homework assignment grade: 20
> - Input homework assignment grade: 20
> - Input project grade: 20
> - Input project grade: 20
> - Input final exam grade: 20
> - Student ID: 123
> - Homework Average: 100
> - Project Average: 100
> - Final exam grade: 100
> - Final average: 100
> - Student ID: -9.25596e+061
> - Homework Average: 140
> - Project Average: 140
> - Final exam grade: 40
> - Final average: 90
> - Student ID: 1
> - Homework Average: 160
> - Project Average: 160
> - Final exam grade: 20
> - Final average: 90
> - Press any key to continue . . .

And I get a stack overflow error. I'm pretty new to C++, and I was making a program that would ask the user for 10 homework assignment grades, 2 project grades, and a final exam grade from 10 students (the numbers in my program are lower so that I could test it easier). I was going to average the homework grades and the project grades separately, then average those averages, then average that average with the final exam grade for a total average (sorry about all the averages), but it doesn't seem to be working and I have no idea why. Like I said, I'm pretty new to C++, and even newer to arrays, so do you think that any of you can give me some insight as to where I went wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you think that declaring variables on the same line will make your code any faster?

Comment: And how about declaring different variables for the loops? Instead of using `i` throughout

Comment: I wasn't thinking about making it faster by declaring them all on the same line, it's just easier for me to visualize it, and it looks a bit more visually efficient to me. Honestly, it's just visual stuff.

Comment: `hwAverage[10] ` , `projectAverage[10]` , `total[10]` and `finalExam[10]` - You are out of bounds here.

Comment: I just noticed those and fixed them, and I've added some more variables for loops, yet I can't seem to get it working. In fact, only the averages for the first student work, then the next students have incorrect information. I've updated the code above.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but "Visual stuff" matters... in the real world at least. I had to scroll to the right to see the rest... I shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays like hwAverage have 10 elements (from [0] to [9]), but you refer to element [10].

Either define more elements or use different index.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `10` as an array index is wrong for arrays that have `10` elements in them. That causes undefined behavior.

Also, using the same `for` loop variable doesn't sound right. You can use `i` for the outer `for` loop and `j` for the inner `for` loops. As the code stands now, your outer `for` loop will never terminate since the value of `i` gets reset in the inner loops.

Use

```
int i;
int j;   // New variable.

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    cout << "Input student ID: ";
    cin >> id[i];
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){  // Use j here
        cout << "Input homework assignment grade: ";
        cin >> hw;

        hwTotal = hwTotal + hw;
    }

    hwAverage[i] = hwTotal / 10;

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++){   // Use j here
        cout << "Input project grade: ";
        cin >> project;

        projTotal = projTotal + project;
    }

    projectAverage[10] = projTotal / 2;  // Fix the index.
                                         // I can't tell what's the right
                                         // index but it has to be  0 - 9.

    projectAverage[i] = projTotal / 2;   // Perhaps???

    hwProj = (hwAverage[10] + projectAverage[10]) / 2; // Fix index here too.
    hwProj = (hwAverage[i] + projectAverage[i]) / 2;   // Perehaps???

    cout << "Input final exam grade: ";
    cin >> finalExam[10];   // Fix index here too.
    cin >> finalExam[i];    // Perhaps???

    total[10] = (finalExam[10] + hwProj) / 2; // Fix index here too.
    total[i] = (finalExam[i] + hwProj) / 2;   // Perhaps???
}
```